# How to test switching to another app and back with Robotium?

Tags: android, android-activity, robotium, activity-lifecycle

I need to test the flow `onPause()` -> `onStop()` -> `onRestart()` -> `onStart()` with `Robotium`. What's the best way to do that? Shall I use `Instrumentation` and call for its methods as I listed one by one or there are some capabilities the `Robotium` library provides? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you will have to do what you thought. Use Instrumentations methods.

Its actually something i have never invested the time in doing in one test as I normally test each step individually when i feel the need to test this sort of stuff.